# Table column merged query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I made a table 
query is

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
     _id             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
   , question        TEXT
   , correct_answer  TEXT    DEFAULT (null)
   , answer1         TEXT    DEFAULT (null)
   , answer2         TEXT    DEFAULT (null) 
   , answer3         TEXT    DEFAULT (null)
   , answer4         TEXT    DEFAULT (null)
   , difficulty      INTEGER DEFAULT (null) 
   , nid             INTEGER
);
```

Now want to omit correct_answer column , and make all right answer in answer1 column, and other 3 incorrect answer in answer2,answer3,answer4. 
But problem is currently right answer could be any of four, so i could not merge

as a example table are like
[image]

u can see in first row correct answer in answer2 and for second row correct answer is in answer4

so how i only take the right answer in answer1 column and other wrong answers in answer2, answer3,answer4 respectively?

what will be the sql query? or any other idea?

Comment: i dont want correctanswer column, instead of correctanswer column i want all the correct answer in answer1 column  and other wrong answers in answer2, answer3,answer4 respectively .but in this table has lots of data how i can change it with contain these data

Comment: Ok, but as a side note, you can do better than this, by having a new table `answers` with a flag `IsCorrect` and a foreign key constraint `QuestionId` to the `questions` table. This will be easier, and your table would be [**normalized**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) this way.

Comment: 1. Normalize your data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for some issue we want to reduce total db size, so if one column could reduce thats a great help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this-

```
SELECT question, correct_answer,
CASE WHEN answer1 != correct_answer THEN answer1 ELSE answer2 END AS incorrect1,
CASE WHEN (answer1 != correct_answer AND answer2 != correct_answer) THEN answer2 ELSE answer3 END AS incorrect2,
CASE WHEN (answer1 != correct_answer AND answer2 != correct_answer AND answer3 != correct_answer) THEN answer3 ELSE answer4 END AS incorrect3
FROM questions
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like this:

```
insert into question_new (_id, qestion, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4)
SELECT _id, question, 
correct_answer as answer1, 
if (correct_answer = answer2 , answer1 , answer2) as answer2,
if (correct_answer = answer3 , answer1 , answer3) as answer3,
if (correct_answer = answer4 , answer1 , answer4) as answer4
 FROM questions
```

In simple:

1. answer1 will always be the correct_answer column.
2. answer2/3/4 will be

   - the same column if different from the correct answer (same as default table)
   - the answer1 if is equal the correct answer (in answer1 there is the correct answer, so you need to set the wrong answer1 in new position)

**update**

Added same query using `case when`

```
insert into question_new (_id, qestion, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4)
SELECT _id, question, 
correct_answer as answer1, 
case when correct_answer = answer2 then answer1 else answer2 end as answer2,
case when correct_answer = answer3 then answer1 else answer3 end as answer3,
case when correct_answer = answer4 then answer1  else answer4 end as answer4
 FROM questions
```

Comment: Thank for the explanation, it solved now, althrough 'if' not valid in sqlite query as i test in sqlite manager.

Comment: you tagged the question as mysql not sqlite... I suggest to use `case when` in sqlite but using equals to compare and not `!=` as  the accepted answer shows, simply because you perform more checks in incorrect2/3 then using `=`

Comment: I've added the same query using IF but with `case when` you should be able to use it in sqlite...

Comment: Thank you very very much, its a great help

Comment: no problem... the best solution is actually the update query because you do not need a temporary table... but you will lose the original table datas and you could not going back...

Answer (score 4):

I would do it this way

```
insert into questions2(_id, qestion, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4)
select _id, question , correct_answer as answer1,
case when correct_answer = answer1 then answer2 else answer1 end answer2,
case when correct_answer = answer2 then answer3 else answer2 end answer3,
case when correct_answer = answer3 then answer4 else answer3 end answer4
from questions
```

So you will end up with new table having your questions in desired format

Answer (score 3):

A little late but you can you can UPDATE your table without needing secondary table to store data as you want

```
UPDATE questions

SET 
answer2 = CASE WHEN answer2 = correct_answer
          THEN answer1 ELSE answer2 END,

answer3 = CASE WHEN answer3 = correct_answer
          THEN answer1 ELSE answer3 END,

answer4 = CASE WHEN answer4 = correct_answer
          THEN answer1 ELSE answer4 END,
answer1 = correct_answer
```

CHECK
**[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32e46/1)**

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the best solution, and that sqlfiidle link, i think it will be a great help for me in future, Thanks a lot